# 1 Form (with dropdown select and text input) using angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I am trying to create a form using the angular.js, of which I know very little. I want the form to pass two fields, a select and input field. This is what I have, however it is only fetching the text input field. Is the form set up correctly?

```html
 <form ng-submit="getStoresByAdd()">
   
         <select>
 <option value="US" selected>United States</option>
 <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
</select>   

      <input type="text" ng-model="wtbSearch" placeholder="ZIP/Postal Code">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button" ng-disabled="disableSubmit">Go</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: where is the `ng-model` for `<select>`? How you are fetching the the dropdown data?

Comment: The select code was my particular problem since that is my addition. What should I code for the dropdown? Is their a particular ng-model for select?

Comment: did you check the docs? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#simple-select-elements-with-static-options

Comment: It looks like it should be:

Comment: <form ng-submit="getStoresByAdd()">
   
     <p>Please select a country.</p>

    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
 <option value="US" selected>United States</option>
 <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
</select>   
      
      <p>Please enter a ZIP/Postal Code.</p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="wtbSearch" placeholder="ZIP/Postal Code">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button" ng-disabled="disableSubmit">Go</button>
    </form>

Comment: I might just need a freelancer to get this right. I have a feeling it's beyond me.

Comment: `ng-model="variableName"`  where `variableName` could be any name depending on  type of input fields and you fetch it in controller by `$scope.variableName`. And you dont require a freelancer for this small task